# How to use an exception outside catch statement

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function that may throw an exception of a variable type, but all inheriting from std::exception:

```
int errorCheck(int a)
{
  if(a < 0)
    throw a_too_small();
  if(a>10)
    throw a_too_big();
  return a*2;
}
```

I want to handle this exception using Qt's SIGNAL/SLOT mechanism.

```
try {
  errorCheck(a);
} catch(std::exception &e) {
  emit errorSignal(e);
}
```

If the signature of `errorSignal` is `errorSignal(std::exception e)`, then the original exception object is sliced and its type is lost.
If the signature is `errorSignal(std::exception &e)` on the other hand, the exception `e` leaves the catch scope, and I believe this is not allowed.

What's the cleanest solution to handle this problem?

Comment: If you can use C++11 maybe can you use [`std::exception_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr)?

Comment: Aren't slots called from within the signal call?  In that case, you're not going outside the lifetime of the exception object.

Comment: Yes they are, at least if you use direct signalling. For example, if the receiver is in another thread, direct signalling is not used. It is enforcable though but would limit the use cases.

Comment: I hope you are only using the exception for exceptional situations. Some people tend to use it for low control, which is not a good idea/design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using C++11 is possible, you can try to use [`std::exception_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr):

```
try {
  ...
} catch (...)
  std::exception_ptr except = std::current_exception();
  emit signal(except);
}
```

Then in your slot:

```
void myslot(std::exception_ptr e) {
  try {
    if (e) {
      std::rethrow_exception(e);
    }
  } catch (...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making the `errorSignal` function signal/slot work by reference? something like `errorSignal(std::exception& e)`? Do that with `Qt::DirectConnection` too to avoid event queuing, with something like:

```
connect(someWidget,SomeWidget::errorSignal&,this,MainWindow::handleError&,Qt::DirectConnection);
```